# CSS image-rendering: pixelated; is ignored on iPhone - workarounds?

Tags: html, css, ios, iphone, mobile

I'm trying to use upscaled pixel art as my page background but I have found that on my iPhone it looks blurry. I have used `image-rendering: pixelated;` with seemingly no effect, however I have found that by making `background-size: cover` or `contain;` will cause the upscaled image to still appear pixelated. Unfortunately I desire a repeating background that is upscaled by an exact pixel amount to maintain aspect ratio. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNN7r.png) is the result on iPhone browsers and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4l2Wb.png) is the **correct** result on desktop browsers. If you can drop any knowledge about how/why this happens and any workarounds you're aware of, or if it's also an issue with android - let me know.

Here's the code from the example:

```css
    *{
        image-rendering:pixelated;
    }
  
  body{
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqpwS.gif');
        background-repeat:repeat;
        background-size: 256px 128px;
  }
  
  #test{
    outline: 1px red solid;
        background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqpwS.gif');
        background-size: cover;
        width:100%;
        height: 100px;
```

```html
<body>
    
    <div id="test">
    </div>
    
</body>
```